# Suitescript: Workflow Action script sent emails not appearing in transaction tab

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have created a workflow action script to send emails so that I can process the incoming messages later on with a email plugin (this might be redundant though I am just experimenting with workflow action scripts at the moment)

This is the script:

```js
    /**
     *@NApiVersion 2.x
     *@NScriptType WorkflowActionScript
     */
    define(["N/email", "N/render", "N/record"], function (email, render, record) {
      function onAction(context) {
        var transaction = context.newRecord;
        var transactionId = transaction.getValue({ fieldId: "tranid" });
        log.debug("transaction Id", transactionId);
        var recipient = transaction.getValue({
          fieldId: "custbody_first_approver",
        });
        var recipientId = parseInt(recipient);
    
        var vendorId = transaction.getValue({ fieldId: "entity" });
    
    
        var mergeResult = render.mergeEmail({
          templateId: 11,
    
          
    
          entity: {
            type: "vendor",
            id: parseInt(vendorId),
          },
    
          recipient: {
            type: "employee",
            id: parseInt(recipient),
          },
          supportCaseId: null,
          transactionId: transactionId,
          customRecord: null,
        });
        var emailSubject = mergeResult.subject;
        var emailBody = mergeResult.body;
        email.send({
          author: -5,
 
          recipients: parseInt(recipient),
    
          subject: "test",
          body: emailBody,
          relatedRecords: {
            transactionId: transactionId,
          },
        });
      }
    
      return {
        onAction: onAction,
      };
    });
```

The email is being sent though a copy of it only seems to be getting stored against the recipient's (who is an employee) entity record.

Looking at the Netsuite guide on the 'N/email' module, it suggests the

```js
    relatedRecords: {
                transactionId: transactionId,
              },
```

part of the script should be controlling where the message is stored. However, there is nothing in the transaction record under the related records or any other tab.

What do I need to change to get a copy of the email message saved against the transaction record?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue. It was this line:

```
var transactionId = transaction.getValue({ fieldId: "tranid" });
```

It needed to be

```
var transactionId = transaction.getValue({ fieldId: "id" });
```

in order to pick up the internal id of the record and not just the transaction number.

All references to it in the script needed to be converted to integer values since otherwise I kept getting the "Wrong parameter type: options.transactionId is expected as number" error.

I converted this by using `parseInt(transactionId)` every time I referred to the transaction ID

Comment: transaction.id will do the trick without the need for parsing or using getValue